# alignment on two columns

Tags: lists, two-column, enumitem

I want to have my list in a two-column format, as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqj4l.jpg). I'm not sure which commands to use.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{\large Math 194 Tutorial 7 Solution}} 
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{Question 1} }
\end{center}
(a) $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$\\
(b) $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$\\
(c) $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$\\
(d) $(a+5b)(12x+3)$\\
(e) $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1)$\\
(f) $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I wan to align my list as the layout in the picture I uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you load the `multicol` package in the preamble and replace

```
(a) $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$\\
(b) $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$\\
(c) $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$\\
(d) $(a+5b)(12x+3)$\\
(e) $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1)$\\
(f) $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$\\
```

with

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$
\item $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$
\item $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$
\item $(a+5b)(12x+3)$
\item $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1)$
\item $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

In words: Set up a two-column environment, and use an `enumerate` environment.

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol} % <--- new

%%%\linespread{2} % don't set "\linespread" directly
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%\underline{
\textbf{\large Math 194 Tutorial 7 Solution} %}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
%\underline{
\textbf{Question 1} %}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$
\item $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$
\item $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$
\item $(a+5b)(12x+3)$
\item $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1)$
\item $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a horizontal numbering, you can use the `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{\large Math 194 Tutorial 7 Solution}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\underline{\textbf{Question 1} }
\end{center}

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $(2z-13)(5x +4y)$ \\
\task $(3a-2c)(6a -7b)$ \\
\task $(3x+5a)(3x-5y)$ \\
\task $(a+5b)(12x+3)$ \\
\task $(6c+7d)(5c^2 -1) $ \\
\task $(3a-5c)(6b+13c)$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]